# Condition in map function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, map-function

Is there anything in Scala like,

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

that I can use within map function in scala?
I want to be able to write something like this:

```
val statuses = tweets.map(status => status.isTruncate? //do nothing | status.getText())
```

If the inline function is not possible, how can I write a condition within `map`?

Answer (score 46):

The `?` operator, sometimes called the *ternary operator* is not necessary in Scala, since it is subsumed by a regular `if-else` expression:

```
val x = if (condition) 1 else 2
```

To use this in a `map`, you can use `flatMap` and then return an `Option` on either side of the `if-else`.  Since `Option` is implicitly convertible to `Iterable`, the effect is that the list is flattened, and the `Nones` are filtered:

```
val statuses = tweets.flatMap(status => if (status.isTruncate) None else Some(status.getText))
```

This is equivalent to using `map` and then `flatten`:

```
val statuses = tweets.map(status => if (status.isTruncate) None else Some(status.getText)).flatten
```

More idiomatically, you can use `collect`, which allows you to `filter` and `map` in one step using a partial function:

```
val statuses = tweets.collect {
    case status if !status.isTruncate => status.getText
}
```

You can also do this in 2 steps using `filter` and `map`:

```
val statuses = tweets.filterNot(_.isTruncate).map(_.getText)
```

The downside here is that this will iterate over the list twice, which may be undesirable.  If you use `view`, you can use this same logic and only iterate over the list once:

```
val statuses = tweets.view.filterNot(_.isTruncate).map(_.getText)
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged [tag:apache-spark], `tweets` is likely an RDD. In that case there is no `filterNot` method, and no `views`. However, RDDs are lazy by nature, so there is no need for `views` either.

Comment: We can also use `withFilter` to do the filtering only in the subsequent operations like `map`. https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#withFilter(p:A=>Boolean):scala.collection.WithFilter[A,CC]

Answer (score 2):

you can filter and then map like,

```
  val statuses = tweets.filter(_.isTruncate).map(status=> status.getText())
```

Comment: This is _not_ the preferred way to approach resolving the problem. It causes the filtered items to be traversed two times; all items for the filter pass and then the successfully filtered items a second time. Given a large list and a substantial percentage which is kept with the filter, your solution is also quite inefficient. BTW, Ben's answer's last line uses a view which can move your solution to becoming efficient.